# Dynamic div container text area looses its value on 3rd attempt

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a div dynamically with "Add to list..." button. The dynamic div is divided in two parts the header and the content. Both parts of the div have onclick event that displays the text on the clicked part in the textarea. There is a textarea blur event which makes the div return to its original form.

The problem comes when I do the click on any of the div part for the 3rd time. It textarea box losses it value and start showing ""

Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated. I'm sharing the complete code below for clear understanding.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Create Div Element Dynamically</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            min-width: 520px;
        }

        .column {
            width: 170px;
            float: left;
            padding-bottom: 100px;
        }

        .portlet {
            margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
            padding: 0.3em;
        }

        .portlet-header {
            padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            position: relative;
        }

        .portlet-toggle {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 0;
            margin-top: -8px;
        }

        .portlet-content {
            padding: 0.4em;
        }

        .portlet-placeholder {
            border: 1px dotted black;
            margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
            height: 50px;
        }

        div {
            min-height:20px;
        }

        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            resize:vertical;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".column").sortable({
                connectWith: ".column",
                handle: ".portlet-header",
                cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
                placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
            });

            $(".portlet")
              .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
              .find(".portlet-header")
                .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
                .prepend("<span class='ui-icon portlet-toggle ui-icon-minusthick'></span>");

            $(".portlet-toggle").click(function () {
                var icon = $(this);
                icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
                icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
            });
        });

        function createDiv() {
            //alert("Test!!");
            var divTag = document.createElement("div");

            divTag.className = "column";
            divTag.innerHTML = "<div class='portlet'>" +
                               "<div class='portlet-header'><span class='rubrik' onclick='divClicked(this)'>Feeds</span></div>" +
                               "<div class='portlet-content' onclick='divClicked(this)'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>" +
                               "</div>";

            document.body.appendChild(divTag);

            $(".column").sortable({
                connectWith: ".column",
                handle: ".portlet-header",
                cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
                placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
            });

            $(".portlet")
              .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
              .find(".portlet-header")
                .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
                .prepend("<span class='ui-icon portlet-toggle ui-icon-minusthick'></span>");

            $(".portlet-toggle").click(function () {
                var icon = $(this);
                icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
                icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
            });
        }

    function divClicked(placeholder) {
        var divHtml = $(placeholder).html();
        var editableText = $("<textarea>");
        $(placeholder).html(editableText.val(divHtml));
        $(placeholder).removeAttr("onclick");
        editableText.focus();
        editableText.blur(function () {
            editableTextBlurred(placeholder, editableText);
        });
    }

    function editableTextBlurred(placeholder, editableText) {
        var html = $(editableText).val();
        $(placeholder).on('click', function () {
            divClicked(placeholder);
        });
        var viewableText = html;
        $(editableText).replaceWith(viewableText);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <input id="button"
               type="button"
               value="Add to list..." onclick="createDiv();" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hardly want to decode your whole script, but I am going to go out on a limb and say its most likely your logic.

Comment: If you would dumb down the scripts and drop into www.jsfiddle.net I'm sure you'll get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function **editableTextBlurred** replace

```
$(placeholder).on('click', function () {
        divClicked(placeholder);
    });
```

with

```
$(placeholder).attr("onclick","divClicked(this)");
```

Should Work. :)